# Rails routing: Handling multiple nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

The following scenario:

```
    resources :first do
        resources :second do
            resources :third do
                resources :fourth do
                    resources :fifth
                end
            end
        end
        resources :third do
            resources :fourth do
                resources :fifth
            end
        end
    end

    resources :second do
        resources :third do
            resources :fourth do
                resources :fifth
            end
        end
    end

    resources :third do
        resources :fourth do
            resources :fifth
        end
    end

    resources :fourth do
        resources :fifth
    end
```

As you can see, I am using multiple levels of nested resources. The way I set this up feels pretty *repetitive* though.
Is there a way to make this more clean?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but I would highly advise you to reconsider your routing scheme. Having 5 levels of nested resources will become extremely cumbersome. I would have a look at [Jamis Buck's short paper](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources) discussing nested resources.

Comment: @Mark You are right. I just wanted to know if there is a way to prevent duplication in routes theoretically. I am not planning to nest resources four or five levels :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`routing concerns`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns) to avoid duplication in your routes, e.g.:

```
concern: :my_concern
  resources :fourth do
    resources :fifth
  end
end

resources :third, concerns: :my_concern
```